# Changing the Height of a wxToolBar

Tags: c++, resize, toolbar, wxwidgets

I want to set the height of a toolbar to the same height as it's neighboring tool bar. I'm setting these toolbars up with an .xrc file. Here's what I'm seeing:

[image]

And here's my .xrc markup:

```
<object class="sizeritem">
    <flag>wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wxALL</flag>
    <border>0</border>
    <object class="wxToolBar" name="ID_TOOLBAR">
        <style>wxTB_FLAT|wxTB_HORIZONTAL</style>
        <bitmapsize>32,32</bitmapsize>
        <dontattachtoframe>1</dontattachtoframe>
        <object class="tool" name="ID_TOOL_RUN">
            <bitmap>tool_run.png</bitmap>
            <label>Run</label>
        </object>
        <object class="tool" name="ID_TOOL_PAUSE">
            <bitmap>tool_pause.png</bitmap>
            <label>Puase</label>
        </object>
        <object class="tool" name="ID_TOOL_STOP">
            <bitmap>tool_stop.png</bitmap>
            <label>Stop</label>
        </object>
    </object>
</object>
<object class="sizeritem">
    <flag>wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wxALL</flag>
    <border>0</border>
    <object class="wxToolBar" name="ID_TOOLBAR3">
        <style>wxTB_FLAT|wxTB_HORZ_TEXT|wxTB_NOICONS</style>
        <margins>32,32</margins>
        <dontattachtoframe>1</dontattachtoframe>
        <object class="separator">
        </object>
        <object class="tool">
            <label>Auto Attack</label>
        </object>
    </object>
</object>
```

I have tried to resize `ID_TOOLBAR3` with both `margins` and `bitmapsize` neither has any effect. Is there something else I can do?

**EDIT:** I've also tried using the `SetSize` to adjust the height in code and I cannot seem to do it. Something is locking it to this small height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well an ugly solution seems to be to actually draw the bitmap *and* the text, but have the bitmap be 0 width and use a transparent 1x1 bitmap: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXZKH.png

I was able to validate this works by:

1. Removing `wxTB_NOICONS` from `ID_TOOLBAR3`'s `style`
2. Using a 0-width `bitmapsize` in `ID_TOOLBAR3`
3. Adding *tXZKH.png* to `ID_TOOLBAR3`'s child

```
<object class="sizeritem">
    <flag>wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wxALL</flag>
    <border>0</border>
    <object class="wxToolBar" name="ID_TOOLBAR3">
        <style>wxTB_FLAT|wxTB_HORZ_TEXT</style>
        <bitmapsize>0, 32</bitmapsize>
        <dontattachtoframe>1</dontattachtoframe>
        <object class="separator">
        </object>
        <object class="tool">
            <bitmap>tXZKH.png</bitmap>
            <label>Auto Attack</label>
        </object>
    </object>
</object>
```

[image]